# Setting label in Java on button click

Tags: java

In an applet I am using  a `button`. Can we set three labels on click of a button 3 times?

Comment: Yes, you can (whatever your question means). Please be more specific, explain what you're trying to do, include the code you tried, and explain what doesn't work with this code.

Comment: i want to set 3 different text on the same label depending upon the clicks on the button

Comment: So, what have you tried? Where's your code?

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this?

```
int count = 0;
String[] texts = new String[] {"Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"};

yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if(count < 3) yourLabel.setText(texts[count]);
        count++;
    }

});
```